# Don't understand this sentence

Tags: meaning

> So, Rosalind avers, Orlando is going to have to put up with someone who never wants the same thing twice, and never is the same person on any two occasions: “I will be more jealous of thee than a Barbary cock-pigeon over his hen, ...”

This is a part of a sentence, and I can understand that the long speech in quotation mark links to “Rosalind avers”, but I don’t quite get the part in the middle which is

> Orlando is going to have to put up with someone who never wants the same thing twice, and never is the same person on any two occasions

Does it mean or link to anything in this sentence?

Comment: "Orlando is going to have to put up with someone who never wants the same thing twice, and never is the same person on any two occasions" means "Orlando is going to have to deal with a ***capricious*** person", where *capricious* means: https://www.google.com/#q=define%20capricious

Comment: The words could also mean that Orlando will have to put up with someone who is hard to please (or difficult to please). What pleases him/her on one occasion does not please him/her on another occasion, so the one who is trying to please him or her is left guessing what exactly will please him or her.

Comment: I think this should be reopened. The question at the end suggests that OP's problem is sorting out the structure of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> So, Rosalind avers, Orlando is going to have to put up with someone who never wants the same thing twice, and never is the same person on any two occasions: "I will be more jealous of thee than a Barbary cock-pigeon over his hen ..."

The phrase *Rosalind avers* is comma-bracketed, marking it as lying outside the sentence into which it is inserted—you could also bracket it in parentheses:

> So (Rosalind avers), Orlando is going to have to ...

In fact it is a speech attribution, like "she said". The remainder of the sentence—the core sentence—is **what** she averred.

Note that it is this averral, not *Rosalind avers*, which is introduced by the adverb *so* = "therefore" or "consequently". It may be that his desire to use *so* here is why Mr. Edmundson places his attribution internally: after *that* (explicit or implicit), *so* would have either ambiguous reference or a different meaning ("in this manner"), or both, and would have to be replaced with a paraphrase:

> <sup>?</sup> Rosalind avers that so Orlando is going to have to ...
>   <sup>ok</sup>Rosalind avers that consequently, Orlando is going to have to ...

The core sentence may be parsed thus:

```
 So,
   Orlando is going to have to put up
   with someone who  never wants the same thing twice
                     and
                     never is the same person on any two occasions
```

The colon introduces a quotation which purports to illustrate this reading:

> I will be more jealous of thee than a Barbary cock-pigeon over his hen, more clamorous than a parrot against rain, more newfangled than an ape, more giddy in my desires than a monkey. I will weep for nothing, like Diana in the fountain, and I will do that when you are disposed to be merry. I will laugh like a hyena, and that when thou art inclined to sleep.

Comment: Hi, I get confused when I was reading "Note that it is this averral, not Rosalind avers, which is introduced by the adverb so", you are talking about the how to understand "Rosalind avers" but why you point out "not Rosalind avers"? Is it a problem with my understanding of your sentences?

Comment: @HUN There seemed to be some confusion in your question. I'm trying to make it clear that 1) you parse this as "So Orlando is going to have to ...", not *So Rosalind avers" and that what she avers is "So Orlando is ...", not the quotation.  The quotation is an illustration of the averral.

Comment: oh So "Rosalind avers" is just there to clarify that the averral is made by Rosalind. And the meaning won't change even if I ditch  "Rosalind avers" .

Comment: @HUN You got it. The Cambridge Grammar calls `,Rosalind avers,` a "supplement".